# Include files without executing anything more than class declaration

Tags: php, include

Can you think of any efficient way (so, `file_get_contents` + regex + `eval` is too heavy) of include files without executing anything but classes declaration? So, just execute code like:

```
class A {
  //Whatever
}
```

And ignore any other statement like `echo`or whatever...

I know it's related with a bad practice, but I'm working with files that are not mine and I can't change it.

Comment: The question is.. why don't you have separate files for your classes?!

Comment: Because are files that are not mine I can't change :)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to have your classes in separate files. If you have PHP 5.1 or above you can use auto loading so it will only include the file/class if you need it. [spl_autoload_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: Yeah, I know. But they are files not written by me and that I can't change :)